# Fetch API not working with Rails + React from Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch-api, webpacker

how to get work Fetch API with Rails and React.

Setup: Rails 5, Sprockets and React from Webpacker.

What I'm trying to achieve here is use Fetch API to fetch and load data to ReactBootstrapTable API.

```
import React from 'react';
import {BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn} from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import 'whatwg-fetch'

class ExampleTable extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      datatable: [], // I'm not sure if I can use array to json data.
    };
  } 
  
  // I'm new to React, so I'm not sure if I'm passing props right  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('start componentDidMount');
    fetch('https://www.test.com/test.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(response) {
        let datatable = response;
        this.setStates({ datatable });
    }).catch(function(ex) {
      console.log('parsing failed', ex);
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BootstrapTable
          data={this.states.datatable} //Here, I'm passing data to the table
          pagination
          striped hover condensed
          options={ { noDataText: 'Empty Table' } }>
          
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id' width='80px' dataAlign='center'>
            ID
          </TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='test'width='300px' dataAlign='left'>
            Test
          </TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default ExampleTable;
```

The main problem here is that I'm not able to use Fetch API and also I'm not totally sure about the way I'm passing data to the table (basically how to use react)

I'm getting a error/warning from my IDE

> fetch is not defined

And another error message from the Firefox console:

> The above error occurred in the  component: in ExampleTable
>
> TypeError: this.states is undefined

I installed the Fetch API through yarn and checked the node_modules/whatwg-fetch folder. As described from the github API, I imported 'whatwg-fetch' as showed in the code above.

I don't know what else I should do. I installed ReactBoostrapTable in the same way and got succeeded doing it. Everything else is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [installation instructions](https://github.com/github/fetch#installation) of fetch for use with webpack, it says to add this to your webpack configuration:

```
entry: ['whatwg-fetch', ...]
```

Also, you mentioned the other error `TypeError: this.states is undefined`. It looks like you have a typo. In React, if you're trying to refer to state, you use it like this:

```
this.state.datatable
```

In your `render` method, you refer to `this.states`.

Also, when you're making your call with fetch, you're trying to call `this.setStates`. You should instead be using it like this:

```
this.setState({ somestate: "xyz"})
```

Comment: Thanks for seeing the typos! haha Fixing these gives me another error message in the console, but it seems now that the compile is reaching the fetch method! It's a progress hehe. About the installation instructions, I think it wouldn't work because what I using is Webpacker and not Webpack.